# I have implemented the in-app update functionality in android using java but I am getting an InstallException exception

Tags: java, android, in-app-update

Exception:  "com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException: Install Error(-3): The API is not available on this device"

Any solution to overcome this scenario? Thanks in advance.

```
        // Creates instance of the manager.
    appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(getApplicationContext());


    // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
    com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();



    // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AppUpdateInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
            Log.e("AVAILABLE_VERSION_CODE", appUpdateInfo.availableVersionCode()+"");

        }


    });

    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", "oops I am HERE in failure "+e);
        }
    });

    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnCompleteListener(new com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnCompleteListener<AppUpdateInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task<AppUpdateInfo> task) {
            Log.e("STATUS", "Completed");
        }
    });

    appUpdateManager.registerListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
```

Comment: Hi, you may provide minimal code to reproduce the error, that way people will assist you quickly.

Comment: @NatitionChirara I have updated the code, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution might be replacing **com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task** with **Task**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look here. [In-App Update gives InstallException (ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718191/in-app-update-gives-installexception-error-api-not-available)
You will find your possible solution.

***Though the In-App Update feature isn't highly recommended nowadays.***