# google play core library not able to detect updated version of application

Tags: android, google-play-core

I have integrated app update feature with google play core library version -

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.3'
```

I am checking for new update as-

```
    public void checkforUpdate(){
    appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo().addOnSuccessListener(
                    appUpdateInfo -> {
                        // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
                        if ((appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE)
                                && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE))
                        {
                            // Request the update.
                            try {
                                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                                        appUpdateInfo,  AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, this,REQUEST_APP_UPDATE);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
}
```

But this code returns as no update available even if a new version application is available on the play store. In a few mobile phones if I clear the cache of the play store then this part of code is able to detect a new version of the update but not in all mobiles.

Please suggest me some solution to fix this problem. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue in an IMMEDIATE update. this bug also submitted. For now, you can use the flexible update feature it's working properly.

See the below link.

[[In-App Update gives InstallException (ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60718191/10814036][1])

And also use the latest core dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.7.2'
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. will try this one.